# Serving static content on a mounted app

Tags: node.js, express

I have a mounted app that taking requests on the `/myapp/` path. Now I want to serve static content.

The path has to be absolute in the context of my mounted app, but relative to the path of the mount itself.

So, for example, I want the pages on `/myapp/something/` and `/myapp/asd/somethingelse` to all load images, CSS and whatnot from `/myapp/`. The files themselves are in the `public` folder with routing setup for serving static content.

The problem is that I can't put relative paths in my base layout template because if the request path is `/myapp/asd/somethingelse` the browser will look for `/myapp/asd/mystaticcontent.css` and I can't use absolute paths because the path to `myapp` might change which would require manual modification every time I move it.

What I basically need is a way to get that prefix that express hides from the mounted app AND NOTHING ELSE.
There's `request.originalUrl` but that also contains the path that `myapp` is matching on. I don't know how to reliably strip the `request.url` from `request.originalUrl` and it does seem kind of a roundabout way of doing it.

If I had that base URL of my mounted app, I could pass it to the template and then generate an absolute path on the spot.

Edit:
`app.path()` might be what I want but this isn't documented.

Comment: it would be better, to call `express.static` multiple times for every folder that you want to serve. even individual folders, or nested , or write a script that handles all contents by checking the route it was requested. For example `/get/<path>` would pipe the file to client with appropriate headers.